# Getting complete list of attributes while looping through particular lxml elements when using xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml

Let's consider the following xml:

```
from lxml import etree

xmldump = '''<bookstore>  
  <book category="COOKING">  
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>  
    <year>2005</year>  
    <price>30.00</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="en">ggggggg</title>  
    <author>g</author>  
    <year>2006</year>  
    <price>129.99</price>  
  </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="es">hhhhhhh</title>  
    <author>h</author>  
    <year>2007</year>  
    <price>229.99</price>  
  </book>  
    <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="cn">kkkkkkkk</title>  
    <author>k</author>  
    <year>2008</year>  
    <price>329.99</price>  
  </book>  
    <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="ru">llllllllll</title>  
    <author>l</author>  
    <year>2009</year>  
    <price>429.99</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="WEB">  
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>  
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>  
    <year>2003</year>  
    <price>39.95</price>  
  </book>  
</bookstore>'''
```

Now I want to get the value of the `lang` attribute from the book nodes that have `category="CHILDREN"` attribute so I did this:

```
xmlproc = etree.fromstring(xmldump.encode('utf-8'))
books = xmlproc.xpath("//*[@category='CHILDREN']")
```

I got a list of `books` with 4 elements so I went on looping through them so I can get the `lang` attribute value from each of them

```
for b in books:
    language = b.xpath("//title/@lang")
    language2 = b.xpath("//*/@lang")
```

The result was: language = ['en', 'en', 'es', 'cn', 'ru', 'en'] when in fact I was expecting language = ['en'] for the first loop then ['es'] and so on ['cn'] and lastly ['ru'] for the last loop through the books list.

Now the `language & language2` got a list with **all** the en attributes from my initial *xmldump*. So I have asked for attributes from the `b` element **only**, why did I get the whole list of attributes? - where the `b` element(s) is each element from the book list.

Also, what is the correct approach so I can get any specific attributes. Please note that I also need to find children and grandchildren for each particular `b` element so I need to be able to separate and loop through those particular lxml elements and not in the initial `xmlproc`.

Comment: The question is worded a bit confusingly. *I want to get the `en` attribute*. I presume that you mean "I want to get the `book` nodes where the `title` has a `lang` attribute with a value of `en`. And by "`b` element", you mean "`book` element". Is that right?

Comment: I have updated accordingly. So what I need is the `en` attribute **value** and yes, the `b` element is the iteration element through the `books` list.

Comment: Sorry to be a nag, but "the value of the `en` attribute" does not make sense. There are no `en` attributes in your XML; there are only `lang` attributes.

Comment: Why not write out the expected output?

Comment: @mzjn You are right, I am sorry, the lang attribute value is what I need. Have updated the description accordingly. Thank you for your patience

Comment: @Greg The expected output is written, please check the *when in fact I was expecting language = ...* part.

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear IMHO,  but I think you need to change `b.xpath("//title/@lang")` to `b.xpath("title/@lang")`. The double slashes means "find all `title` elements in the whole document", not just the `title` child of the current `book`.

Comment: @mzjn This makes sense and does solve the issue but not my question. So if 'b' represents just a part of the main `xmlproc` why if I search something **inside** `b` (using //) it does search the entire `xmlproc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.xpath("//title/@lang")` & `b.xpath("//*/@lang")` the double backslashes will retrieve all the data from the xml (and not your filtered results). Simply remove it:

```
from lxml import etree

xmldump = '''<bookstore>  
  <book category="COOKING">  
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>  
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>  
    <year>2005</year>  
    <price>30.00</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="en">ggggggg</title>  
    <author>g</author>  
    <year>2006</year>  
    <price>129.99</price>  
  </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="es">hhhhhhh</title>  
    <author>h</author>  
    <year>2007</year>  
    <price>229.99</price>  
  </book>  
    <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="cn">kkkkkkkk</title>  
    <author>k</author>  
    <year>2008</year>  
    <price>329.99</price>  
  </book>  
    <book category="CHILDREN">  
    <title lang="ru">llllllllll</title>  
    <author>l</author>  
    <year>2009</year>  
    <price>429.99</price>  
  </book>  
  <book category="WEB">  
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>  
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>  
    <year>2003</year>  
    <price>39.95</price>  
  </book>  
</bookstore>'''

xmlproc = etree.fromstring(xmldump.encode('utf-8'))
books = xmlproc.xpath("// *[@category='CHILDREN']")
for b in books:
    language = b.xpath("title/@lang")
    language2 = b.xpath("*/@lang")
    print(language)
    print(language2)
```

**Output:**

```
['en']
['en']
['es']
['es']
['cn']
['cn']
['ru']
['ru']
```

You can move the logic from the for loop into the xpath:

```
languageArr = xmlproc.xpath("// *[@category='CHILDREN'] //title/@lang")    
print(languageArr)

language2Arr = xmlproc.xpath("// *[@category='CHILDREN'] //*/@lang")
print(language2Arr)
```

**Output:**

```
['en', 'es', 'cn', 'ru']
['en', 'es', 'cn', 'ru']
```

Comment: This makes sense and does solve the issue but not my question. So if 'b' represents just a part of the main xmlproc why if I search something inside b (even using //) it does search the entire xmlproc?

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit, 'b' is a reference to an xml element. It will also contain a reference to the entire XML object so that you can traverse up the chain

Comment: I never thought of it this way, I was thinking as if  `b` was just just a fraction of the main XML object and the logic was that I cannot find elements other than the ones contained by `b` inside the main XML object - that's why I never thought of not using the backslash(es). I still don't understand this logic but I'll just take it as a fact. Thank you!

Comment: Whilst b is a python class, it represents an XML node. etree is built to use `xpath` language to navigate around an XML tree. As a result double backslashes will search the entire xml.